# Is there a more effecient way to calculate and use Perlin noise?

Tags: c#, noise, perlin-noise

I just started using Perlin noise a few days ago, and the results look quite good. But it takes over 3 seconds to calculate and draw a 1024x1024 bitmap of said noise. I use an array of 1024x1024 to store int32's ranging from -1 to 1.

The code that creates the array of Perlin noise:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sw.Start();
        LibNoise.Perlin perlinMap = new LibNoise.Perlin();
        perlinMap.Lacunarity = lacunarity + 0.01d;
        perlinMap.NoiseQuality = LibNoise.NoiseQuality.High;
        perlinMap.OctaveCount = octaveCount;
        perlinMap.Persistence = persistence;
        perlinMap.Frequency = frequency;
        perlinMap.Seed = 1024;

        if (radioButton1.Checked)
            perlinMap.NoiseQuality = LibNoise.NoiseQuality.Low;
        else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            perlinMap.NoiseQuality = LibNoise.NoiseQuality.Standard;
        else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            perlinMap.NoiseQuality = LibNoise.NoiseQuality.High;

        double sample = trackBar6.Value * 10;

        double[,] perlinArray = new double[resolutieX, resolutieY];
        for (int x = 0; x < resolutieX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < resolutieY; y++)
            {
                perlinArray[x, y] = perlinMap.GetValue(x / sample, y / sample, 1d);
            }
        }
        draw(perlinArray);
        textBox12.Text = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms";
        sw.Reset();
    }
```

The code that draws out the perlin noise:

```
 public void draw(double[,] array)
    {
        Bitmap afbeelding = new Bitmap(1024, 1024);
        Color color;
        int tileSize = 1024 / resolutieY;
        for (int y = 1; y < resolutieY; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 1; x < resolutieX; x++)
            {
                if (array[x, y] <= -0.2)
                    color = Color.DarkBlue;
                if (array[x, y] <= 0)
                    color = Color.DarkBlue;
                else if (array[x, y] <= 0.1)
                    color = Color.Blue;
                else if (array[x, y] <= 0.2)
                    color = Color.Beige;
                else if (array[x, y] <= 0.22)
                    color = Color.LightGreen;
                else if (array[x, y] <= 0.40)
                    color = Color.Green;
                else if (array[x, y] <= 0.75)
                    color = Color.DarkGreen;
                else if (array[x, y] <= 0.8)
                    color = Color.LightSlateGray;
                else if (array[x, y] <= 0.9)
                    color = Color.Gray;
                else if (array[x, y] <= 1)
                    color = Color.DarkSlateGray;
                else
                    color = Color.DarkSlateGray;

                //  color = Color.FromArgb(255);

                for (int i = 0; i < tileSize; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < tileSize; j++)
                    {
                        afbeelding.SetPixel(((x - 1) * tileSize) + i, ((y - 1) * tileSize) + j, color);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = afbeelding;
    }
```

Should I be using Simplex noise? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Most likely the `SetPixel` is your bottleneck. Look into unsafe bitmap editing in c#.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving the performance of working code. Please ask your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with perlin noise.

Comment: @Euphoric added the Perlin noise code

Comment: Does it have to be Perlin noise? Because you could use Simplex noise for a similar result, but it's easier to calculate http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_noise

Answer (score 2):

You should use [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits.aspx) instead of SetPixel when reading or writing big chunks of image.

And make sure you are running the code in Release mode without attached debugger. Both of those can dramatically affect performance.

Simplex noise is not going to help here, because it gains performance on higher dimensions. There probably isn't any performance gain for 2D noise.

Answer (score 0):

> calculate and use

These are two distinct beasts with many different approaches each.
You may save a lot of time by storing results of perlin noise or whatever expensive implicit evaluation in data structures. 
If you want to sustain a decent frame rate in your application, it is not really a good idea to evaluate noise in real-time even on modern HW because it will eat a lot of processing resources. Once stored in data structures, you reduce the processing to a simple access to this structure which is substantially much cheaper, and usually giving you back most of your processing budget.